# Updating AWS CLI on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I installed `awscli` on my EC2 instance using `apt-get install`.

The version is still `aws-cli/1.2.9` and no longer updates if I use `apt-get upgrade awscli`. The latest release from what I Googled is  1.10.30.

How can you **update aws cli** on Ubuntu 14.04?

Thank you.

*PS. Other than using pip since I don't have that.*

Comment: What's preventing you from installing `pip`? I guess you could use `easy_install` or manually download the source distribution.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the explanation on how you can perform the upgrade.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

Here's what did the job for me:

```
To install the AWS CLI using the bundled installer
Download the AWS CLI Bundled Installer using wget or curl.
Unzip the package.

Run the install executable.

On Linux and OS X, here are the three commands that correspond to each step:

curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but the important/relevant information from the link should be included in the answer.
In general, it’s best for answers to be as self-contained as possible.
Always quote the most relevant part of the external resource as its URL may change or go permanently offline.